# Whats the best technology stack for supporting mobile apps and a website from the same back-end?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, json, rest, mobile

I will have native iPhone and Android apps, and later a mobile web site (for other mobile platforms) all talking to a back-end that manages users, settings, video, social graphs, etc. I will also have a dynamic web site with a lot of video, pictures, and social graph administration. The web site will basically be a more featureful version of the apps on the phones. The back-end consists of video storage, transcoding, a video recommendation engine, options to share the video with your network.

My thought is that I should build a common applications services layer that exposes a RESTful api that returns JSON, and have both the apps and the web site talk to this api.

My question is should I keep the web site and the services layer both in one technology or use Java for the services layer, and Rails or Python for the web site to take advantage of their purported faster dev time. The site will have a lot of JavaScript and AJAX to support dynamic behavior. If I use Rails or Python, should they also talk REST/JSON to the services layer? In terms of deployment and scaling management, it would seem like sticking with one technology like Java for all back-end pieces might be better; but on the other hand Rails and Python promise faster development and maintenance times for the web layer. If I use Rails for the web tier, would it make sense to deploy it in JRuby within the same JVM as the services layer to have fewer moving parts to manage on the web/app server?

The site may grow to millions of users and videos. The development team are experienced at Java, with some Python, but are smart and can quickly learn other technologies.

Feel free to suggest the technology stack of your choice.

Comment: This is highly subjective and way too broad; You're asking something that a lot of companies are basing their whole business on and have evolved over a decade; mobile didn't happen with iPhone, it just got a lot more complex because of it.

Comment: I understand where Archie is coming from though. Even though other companies have evolved this, it's helpful to attempt to implement it properly from the beginning. Architectural mistakes cost a ton of money to fix. I'm here 2 years later looking for the answers to the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some advice based on my experience:

- create a separate API layer for your JSON api. Use Spring MVC or JAX-RS there
- for the web front-end you can use grails - it combines the strengths of dynamic languages like ruby and python with the power of the JVM and the java stack.
- you can choose to use only your API from your site, or expose only some of the features through the API and use the rest internally.
- for internal communication try not to add overhead - you can start with simple service classes (spring beans, for example). Exposing them as web services is harmful, imo. Yes, it appears that your modules are decoupled, but it hampers flexibility. Since services are stateless they can be invoked from any place, so you can easily make them live and be invoked in the same JVM as the grails app.

Comment: Bozho, thanks for a helpful reply. I have some follow-up questions based on your answer:

Comment: You say use Spring MVC "or" JAX-RS. Does it have to be one or the other? Are they equivalent technologies? I have considered using Jersey for exposing a REST api from Java using JAX-RS. Does Spring MVC allow exposing a REST JSON API as well? For the site, you are recommending that I just call the Spring Beans from Grails? Why do you think exposing them as web services hampers flexibility? If a service needs to be used by both mobile and the web site, would I have a service bean AND a REST wrapper? What do you think of jRuby?

Comment: yes, spring mvc allows exposing REST JSON API. You can use spring with jersey and spring with spring mvc (spring mvc is a separate framework)